# Equivalent of Pivot.IsLocked for Panoramas in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, windows-phone-8

Windows Phone 8 introduced a wonderful `IsLocked` property to Pivot controls. Unfortunately, it was not added to Panoramas! Is there any equivalent property or method to prevent user scrolling in a Panorama?